# Use controller method in script to display or hide input field in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with dropdownlist and text field with visibility depending of dropdownlist choice based on database data of chosen item.

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.RaceId = new SelectList(db.Races.OrderBy(o => o.Name), "Id", "Name");
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("RaceId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "race-choice" })
```

**Model**

```
public class Race
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsLongLiver { get; set; }
}
```

I plan to use a script like this

```
$('#race-choice').change(function () {
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
    var isLongLiver = /* pass selectedId into specific Conroller method like
    {
        return (await db.RacesFindAsync(selectedId)).IsLongLiver;
    } */
    if (isLongLiver) {
        $('#long-liver-input').show();
    } else {
        $('#long-liver-input').hide();
    }
});
```

where "long-liver-input" is an id of the  I plan to hide or show.

But there is a problem - I don't know how to implement this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call c# method from jquery.

You need to call controller method using ajax.

For example

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetData(int selectedId)
{
   return Json((await db.RacesFindAsync(selectedId)).IsLongLiver , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Script**

```
$('#race-choice').change(function () {
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       url : '',//controller method url
       data : {selectedId: selectedId},
       success : function(data){
           if (data) {
               $('#long-liver-input').show();
           } else {
               $('#long-liver-input').hide();
           }
       }
    })
});
```

Comment: With fix for making controller method async works just perfect. Thank you.